# Why isn't this join printing the correct results? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

We recently had a contractor in to do some work on our app, and now I'm having to debug it. I'm still quite new to Laravel and I'm struggling to debug the problem. They've left for newer pastures and aren't available to help.

What should be happening is a printout of only the matched results. So let's say we have an Agency id of 141 and they have 1 preferred region, South East Asia.

Let's take user 252 and we find they have multiple preferred regions, 1 of which is South East Asia. I only want to return the matched region.

Currently this is not happening.
Currently, out of user 252's preferences:
No Preference - Any Region
Eastern Europe

We're getting a result of:
Eastern Europe
South East Asia

My assumption is that this section of code here is the culprit? SQL isn't my strong point.

```
/**
         * Match regions with 2 given id's
         *
         * @return Array with the matched regions_id 
         * @author 
         **/
        public function matchRegions ($itemOne, $itemTwo)
        {
            return \App\Regionable::selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, regions_id, description')
              ->join('regions', 'regions_id', '=', 'regions.id')                
              ->where('regionable_id', $itemOne)
              ->orWhere('regionable_id', $itemTwo)
              ->groupBy('regions_id')
              ->havingRaw('cnt > 1')
              ->get();
        }

        public function matchPreferences ($itemOne, $itemTwo)
        {
            return \App\Preferable::selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, ministry__prefs_id, description')
              ->join('ministry_prefs', 'ministry__prefs_id', '=', 'ministry_prefs.id')                
              ->where('preferable_id', $itemOne)
              ->orWhere('preferable_id', $itemTwo)
              ->groupBy('ministry__prefs_id')
              ->havingRaw('cnt > 1')
              ->get();
        }

        public function matchLanguages($itemOne, $itemTwo)
        {
            return \App\Languageable::selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, language_id, subcategory as description')
              ->join('languages', 'language_id', '=', 'languages.id')        
              ->where('languageable_id', $itemOne)
              ->orWhere('languageable_id', $itemTwo)
              ->groupBy('language_id')
              ->havingRaw('cnt > 1')
              ->get();
        }

        public function matchCommitment($itemOne, $itemTwo)
        {
            return \App\Timeable::selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, time__commitment_id, timecommit.description')
              ->join('timecommit', 'time__commitment_id', '=', 'timecommit.id')
              ->where('timeable_id', $itemOne)
              ->orWhere('timeable_id', $itemTwo)
              ->groupBy('time__commitment_id')
              ->havingRaw('cnt > 1')
              ->get();
        }



public function prefCount ()
    {
      return (count($this->regions()->get())+count($this->ministry_prefs()->get())+count($this->languages()->get())+count($this->time_commitment()->get()));      
    }

    public function matchSeeker($userIds = [])
    {
      if(empty($userIds)) $userIds = UserInfo::all()->pluck('id');
      $agencyPrefCount = $this->prefCount();

      foreach ($userIds as $userId) {
        $seekerPrefCount = 0;
        $seeker = [];
        $regions = $this->matchRegions($this->id, $userId);
        $preferences = $this->matchPreferences($this->id, $userId);
        $languages = $this->matchLanguages($this->id, $userId);
        $timecommit = $this->matchCommitment($this->id, $userId);

        if(count($regions) > 0) $seeker['regions'] = $regions;
        if(count($preferences) > 0) $seeker['preferences'] = $preferences;
        if(count($languages) > 0) $seeker['languages'] = $languages;
        if(count($timecommit) > 0) $seeker['timecommit'] = $timecommit;


        if(!empty($seeker)) {
          $seeker['details'] = UserInfo::findOrFail($userId);
          $seekerPrefCount = (count($regions)+count($preferences)+count($languages)+count($timecommit));
          if(($agencyPrefCount == 0) || ($seekerPrefCount == 0)) $seeker['relevance'] = 0;
            else $seeker['relevance'] = round((($seekerPrefCount / $agencyPrefCount) * 100),2); 
          $seekers[$userId] = $seeker;
        }
      }


      $seekers = array_reverse(array_values(array_sort($seekers, function ($value) {
        return $value['relevance'];
      })));

      return $seekers;
    }
```

Printing out the results to the view works something like so:

Controller:

```
public function getDashboard() {

        $agency = Agency::with('ministry_prefs', 'languages', 'time_commitment', 'regions')->findOrFail(Auth::user()->login_id);
        $seekers = $agency->matchSeeker();
        return view('agency-area.home', compact('agency', 'seekers'));
    }
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($seekers as $seekerId => $seeker)
  <?php 
    switch (true) {
      case ($seeker['relevance'] <= 20) :
          $level = 'bg-red';
        break;
      case (($seeker['relevance'] >= 21) && ($seeker['relevance'] <= 30)):
          $level = 'bg-orange';
        break;
      default:
          $level = 'bg-green';
    }
  ?>

    <div class="box-comment">                
   {{ Html::image('img/avatar.jpg', 'User Image', array('class' => 'img-circle img-sm')) }}<!-- User image -->
      {{-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> Like</button> --}}
    <div class="comment-text">
      <span class="username">
        <a href="user/{{ $seeker['details']->id }}">{{((!empty($seeker['details']->name)) ? $seeker['details']->name : $seeker['details']->First_Name." ".$seeker['details']->Last_Name)}} {{$seeker['details']->First_Name." ".$seeker['details']->Last_Name}}</a>
        <span class="text-muted pull-right">{{$seeker['details']->created_at}}</span>
        {{-- <span class="badge {{$level}}">{{$seeker['relevance']}} % <span class="text-white">Match</span></span>          --}}
      </span><!-- /.username -->
        {{$seeker['details']->Experience}}


      <hr/>
      <div class="row">
                @if(!empty($seeker["regions"]))
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h4>Regions</h4>                    
                        @foreach($seeker["regions"] as $region)
                            <small>{{$region->description}}</small><br/>
                        @endforeach
            </div>
                @endif

                @if(!empty($seeker["preferences"]))
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h4>Preferences</h4>                    
                        @foreach($seeker["preferences"] as $preferences)
                            <small>{{$preferences->description}}</small><br/>
                        @endforeach
            </div>
                @endif

                @if(!empty($seeker["languages"]))
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <h4>Languages</h4>                  
                        @foreach($seeker["languages"] as $commitment)
                            <small>{{$commitment->description}}</small><br/>
                        @endforeach
            </div>
                @endif

                @if(!empty($seeker["timecommit"]))
        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <h4>Commitment</h4>
                        @foreach($seeker["timecommit"] as $commitment)
                            <small>{{$commitment->description}}</small><br/>
                            {{-- {{$commitment->time__commitment_id}} --}}
                        @endforeach
            </div>
                @endif

      </div>

    </div> <!-- /.comment-text -->
  </div><!-- /.box-comment -->


@endforeach
```

Comment: so you want us to go through code :)

Comment: Is that an ok question to ask? I'm a bit new. An explanation of what's happening, yeah. Debugging I can handle. :)

Comment: To be sure about user data change `$userIds = UserInfo::all()->pluck('id');` to `$userIds = UserInfo::find($id);` so you can get only one user's data and do your own check. From what i understand, it fetches all users and then sees what data is associated with each user and put it in `$regions, $preferences, $languages, $timecommit`. Also, all this data is stored in something called `$seeker` where `$seeker['id_here_of_user']`. After that, in the view it shows data of all users(seekers).

Comment: Changing pluck to find causes the foreach to fail, probably because find is 1 item, whereas pluck is all the items. I believe it's trying to do what you said, check all the users against the currently logged in user and print out the associated data. 
Only I'm getting results that don't exist on the current user, or are inconsistently matched. Which, and this is a guess, might be because it's comparing the wrong info to the wrong info.

Comment: Did you try with `$userIds = UserInfo::find(1);` where 1 is an ID of user that exists? Also, `switch` can have only `=` and not other compares. For example, `case ($seeker['relevance'] <= 20) :` seems wrong to me

Comment: Wait, there's a switch statement? Where? Also, oh snap. Tested id 141, it fails with "No query results for model [App\UserInfo] 15", that don't look right...

Comment: Change also `$seeker['details'] = UserInfo::findOrFail($userId);` to `$seeker['details'] = UserInfo::find($userId);` and try again in addition with the change i mentioned above. Switch statement is inside the view. * Be sure that the ID exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142249/discussion-between-antonis-tsimourtos-and-mugluck).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, many thanks to @Antonis-Tsimourtos for pointing me in the right direction with debugging.

Putting down my solution at the moment (note I haven't tested how many queries this is making. This solves the problem, but it's innefficient I think).

The issue arises from the joining statement the contractor used:

```
public function matchLanguages($itemOne, $itemTwo)
        {
            return \App\Languageable::selectRaw('count(*) AS cnt, language_id, subcategory as description')
              ->join('languages', 'language_id', '=', 'languages.id')        
              ->where('languageable_id', $itemOne)
              ->orWhere('languageable_id', $itemTwo)
              ->groupBy('language_id')
              ->havingRaw('cnt > 1')
              ->get();
        }
```

ItemOne and Two are the user ids of the accounts being matched against. If you look at the join, it's comparing them, but instead of filtering out the final result, it's tacking on each result with the where and orwhere. Those who use laravel will recognise this is also unnecessary as Laravel's relationships take care of half the query being made here.

The solution is to use those queries, like so:

```
public function matchLanguages($itemOne, $itemTwo)
{

    $languages1 = \App\UserInfo::find($itemOne)->languages()->get();

    $languages2 = \App\Agency::find($itemTwo)->languages()->get();

    return $languages1->intersect($languages2);
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not eager loading these relationships, which is probably the next step in optimisation. But that requires hunting through the code a bit.

Hope that helps!